# Como calcular distancia entre fechas en java?

Tags: java, api, date, calendar

Estoy usando gregorian calendar implementando tambien Date, tengo un codigo con el cual pude establecer fechas validas, pero no encuentro como calcular la distancia entre dos fechas. Estuve leyendo la API pero se me dificulta entender las instrucciones, si tienen algun consejo para alguien que esta empezando a leer la api se agradece. Tenia algunas ideas pero muy vagas. Dejo mi codigo:

```
public Fecha(int d, int m, int a) {
    this.dia = d;
    this.mes = m;
    this.año = a;
    calendario = new GregorianCalendar();
    Date fecha = new Date();
    calendario.setTime(fecha);
    calendario.set(a, m, d);
    
    
    }
public String imprimirFecha() {
        return "la fecha es " + calendario.get(Calendar.DATE) + " " +
                calendario.get(Calendar.MONTH) + " " + calendario.get(Calendar.YEAR);
    }
```

Comment: Como ingresas ambas fechas para compararlas?

Comment: ingreso una fecha, pero no se como guardar otra y compararla, si tenes alguna plantilla para empezar de 0 seria bueno, sea con cualquier interfaz de fecha

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes usar el siguiente mètodo donde obtienes las fechas inicial y final y estableces su diferencia en milisegundos, para imprimir la diferencia en dìas:

```
private static void diferenciaFechas(String fechaInicial, String fechaFinal){
        
    
         String[] fechaI = fechaInicial.split("/");
         String[] fechaF = fechaFinal.split("/");
         
         Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();

           cal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, Integer.parseInt(fechaI[0]));
           cal.set(Calendar.MONTH, Integer.parseInt(fechaI[1]));
           cal.set(Calendar.YEAR, Integer.parseInt(fechaI[2]));
           Date firstDate = cal.getTime();

           cal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, Integer.parseInt(fechaF[0]));
           cal.set(Calendar.MONTH, Integer.parseInt(fechaF[1]));
           cal.set(Calendar.YEAR, Integer.parseInt(fechaF[2]));
           Date secondDate = cal.getTime();
    
           long diferencia = secondDate.getTime() - firstDate.getTime();

           System.out.println ("Diferencia en dias: " + diferencia/1000/60/60/24);
}
```

Este es un ejemplo de como lo llamarìas usando el formato `dd/mm/YYYY` :

```
 diferenciaFechas("27/11/2020","27/11/2021");
```

Tendrìas como salida:

```
Diferencia en dias: 365
```

---

Enviando como int el año, mes y dìa:

```
private static void diferenciaFechas(int dI, int mI, int aI, int dF, int mF, int aF){                
           Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
           cal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, dI);
           cal.set(Calendar.MONTH, mI);
           cal.set(Calendar.YEAR, aI);
           Date firstDate = cal.getTime();

           cal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, dF);
           cal.set(Calendar.MONTH, mF);
           cal.set(Calendar.YEAR, aF);
           Date secondDate = cal.getTime();
           long diferencia = secondDate.getTime() - firstDate.getTime();
           System.out.println ("Diferencia en dias: " + diferencia / 1000 / 60 / 60 / 24);
}
```

llamarìas de esta forma el mètodo:

```
diferenciaFechas(27,11,2020,27,11,2021);
```

Comment: Mala mia, no se podria con int en los parametros?

Comment: Si claro, edite la respuesta.

Comment: Muchas Gracias amigo, tenes la documentacion de donde aprendiste esto?

Comment: Pues seria la documentación de la clase Date y su método getTime(), la documentación oficial es https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#getTime--